# Want to zip the files using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I Want to maintain the last 10 days files in a folder meanwhile i want to zip the files which are (11-20) days back and want to delete the (21-n) files. Can you please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `forfiles /?` will help. Especially take a look to the `/D` Parameter.

Comment: Can you tell me the syntax please.

Answer (score 0):

```
forfiles -D -21
```

will give you all files older than 20 days.

You need a `for` to use the output to another command:

```
for /f %%i in ('forfiles /d -20') do echo del %%i
```

(you will have to remove the `echo` to actually delete the files, but it's a good idea to do it later, if you are sure, that it works the way you want)

As the files older than 20 days now are deleted, you can now zip the files older than 10 days.
Therefore put them into a temporary folder and zip them there:

```
md tempdir
for /f %%i in ('forfiles /d -10') do echo move %%i tempdir\
WhateverZipApplicationyouUse /whateverParametersItNeeds tempdir\*.*
```

Comment: C:\x\y\z is the folder. I want to do the above operation in z folder only. Need clear explanation from you. I am a beginner that's why.

Comment: simply go to the right folder first with `cd /d c:\x\y\z`